# Groovy - remove class field transient modifier using metaClass

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

We have a simple Groovy class:

```
class A implements Serializable {
   transient Integer t // this field is transient in the serialization process
   Object o
}
```

as we know, we can modify properties and methods of a class like that in runtime using Groovy's metaClass property (metaprograming).

What I wan't to do is: **remove the 'transient' modifier from the 't' property of the A class and let it to serialize this field**. I need to do this IN THE RUNTIME using metaClass or another mechanism.

Recompiling, recreating A class won't be a solution. I have this class deployed and running on the server and the only thing I can do with it is changing it's meta-behavior via remote groovy-shell.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go at this, and I don't believe it's possible

Even with using reflection and setting the modifiers on the declared field from the class, serialization still skips the property

I think the only solution would be to write your own serialization routine, ignoring the transient modifier.

Or of course, change the class (but you say this isn't possible)